# Quarkus - Redis lpush and Connection pool reached max wait queue size of 24

Tags: java, list, redis, quarkus

I am using Redis lists and **lpush** for publishing high volume of messages and then having multiple threads to receive the updates using **brpop** command. The code works in a random fashion. it works sometimes and mostly, ends up with the connection pool reached max wait queue size error.
Actually, this is happening when i have 2 classes trying to push/pull from 2 different lists. When i do this in just 1 class, it works fine. Not sure connecting to multiple lists has any overhead.
Am using Redis version 6+ on Quarkus if it helps.

Any idea what is causing the issue and how to resolve?

Thank you in advance!

Best Regards
SG

Comment: Yes increased the maxpoolwaiting to 100

Answer (score 0):

Realized that this was a problem with nested CompletableFutures since I was using the RedisAPI.

Comment: May I know how did you solve this issue?

I am executing 3 Redis commands using vertx Future.all()  and it is giving me same error:

`io.vertx.core.http.ConnectionPoolTooBusyException: Connection pool reached max wait queue size of 24`


I increased it to 100, but still could not cope up with the requests. what should be the ideal way? How to process the requests in batches, means 3 commands in one redis request?

Comment: This was a long time ago but I think I did the solution suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76316944/how-to-enforce-blocking-for-a-vertx-redis-stream-write/76377481#76377481

```
toCompletionStage().toCompletableFuture().join()
```